# Firebase - Grant write access only to a specific location

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How would I be able to let the user write only in a specific part of my real time database e.g. under database>Category1 ?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security. If you're having trouble making that work for your scenario, share the [minimal JSON+rules that show where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you for that quick response, I will take another look at the docs then